# Web mail application not supporting HTML

Tags: html, email

Can you please suggest me some webmail application which does not support embedded HTML?

I have tried to google but unable to locate any.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a difficult thing to find. An option may exist, in some client, to disable reading HTML emails. However, that's a lot more searching, and doesn't guarantee a solution.

If it was my project, I would modify an open source PHP webmail client, like http://www.hastymail.org/.